# IPv6 to IPv4 proxy tunnel

Tags: networking, ssh, proxy, ipv6, tunnel

I am new to IPv6.

I have a IPv6 only vps.  Because the VPS has only a IPv6 address, I am not able to access basic sites like github (which do not have a IPv6 address) as well as other repo sites.

I tried to use sshuttle to route all the traffic via another system which works for IPv6 as well as IPv4.  It does not work either.  The sshuttle log shows

```
root@bh01:~/sshuttle# sshuttle -v 0/0 -NHr user@host
Starting sshuttle proxy.
firewall manager: Starting firewall with Python version 2.7.3
firewall manager: ready method name nat.
IPv6 enabled: False
UDP enabled: False
DNS enabled: False
User enabled: False
TCP redirector listening on ('127.0.0.1', 12300).
Starting client with Python version 2.7.3
c : connecting to server...
Starting server with Python version 3.5.3
 s: latency control setting = True
 s: available routes:
c : Connected.
 s:   2/178.251.25.0/24
c : seed_hosts: []
firewall manager: setting up.
```

The lot says

> IPv6 enabled: False

I do not see any option to force enable IPv6 for sshuttle.  Any way I can enable it?

Or any other way to setup tunnel from IPv6 to IPv4 so that my vps is usable like a normal host?

Answer (score 0):

You can update your ssh_config https://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config to only use ipv4. Since sshuttle uses your native install of ssh it will also be forced to follow your configurations.

```
#    ...
#    CheckHostIP yes
#    AddressFamily any
#    ConnectTimeout 0
#    ...
```

Above commented out is the default configuration. You can uncomment and change this to inet for ipv4 or inet6 for ipv6.

```
#    ...
#    CheckHostIP yes
     AddressFamily inet
#    ConnectTimeout 0
#    ...
```

Afterwards any program that uses ssh will be forced to follow this configuration unless a different configuration is specified when you execute at the command line using the -4 or -6 ssh options.

Comment: Please post text as text, not as screenshots.

Comment: @G-Man is that against site policy? Changed it regardless.

Comment: Maybe not actual *official* policy, but [PSA: Please don’t post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/80216) is a request by a ♦ moderator that’s generally supported by the community.